# how can I apply a function to all dataframe variables?

Tags: r

I want have a dataframe with something like 90 variables, and over 1 million observations. I want to calculate the percentage of NA rows on each variable. I have the following code:
sum(is.na(dataframe$variable) / nrow(dataframe) * 100)
My question is, how can I apply this function to all 90 variables, without having to type all variable names in the code?

Comment: `lapply(df, yourfunction)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `lapply()` with your method:

```
lapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x))/nrow(df)*100)
```

Comment: or this: `lapply(df, function(x) mean(is.na(x)))`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return a `data.frame` rather than a list (via `lapply()`) or a vector (via `sapply()`), you can use `summarise_each` from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum(is.na(.)) / length(.)))
```

or, even more concisely:

```
df %>% summarise_each(funs(mean(is.na(.))))
```

### data

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  y = 1:10,
  z = 1:10
)

df$x[c(2, 5, 7)] <- NA
df$y[c(4, 5)] <- NA
```